# Canvas のプレハブ化が上手くいきません。

Tags: c#, unity3d, ugui

初の質問投稿となります。よろしくお願いします。

uGUI の Textをプレハブから生成した後、 Canvas を親として設定するためにプレハブを使い

```c#
public class NumberText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas UICanvas;     //UIを表示するキャンバス
    void Awake(){
        transform.SetParent(UICanvas.transform, false);
    }
}
```

というように書いたのですが、下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption.

プレハブを使わずに、 Canvas を直接 `GameObject.Find` することで正常に動作してくれたのですが、プレハブ化出来ないのがどうもモヤモヤします。

Inspector 上でプレハブやスクリプトを付け忘れていないことは確認しているのですが…。
 Canvas をプレハブ化して参照するような使い方をすることが間違っているのでしょうか？

また、 Hierarchy にある CanvasはPanel や Image を子オブジェクトとして持つのですが、プレハブ化した際にこれらの子オブジェクトが Project ビューに表示されないことも気になります。

[image: スクリーンショット]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Assets/Prefabs/NumberText.prefab` にアタッチしているNumberTextコンポーネントですが、
UICanvasにInstantiate前の `Prefab` が設定してあるのが問題だと思います。
ProjectView内のPrefabはInsrantiateしないでそのまま使う事はできません

Hierarchy上のCanvasをtransform.SetParent()するといいんじゃないでしょうか

```c#
void Awake(){
    var canvas = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>();
    transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

あと、 ProjectViewには孫以下のGameObjectは表示されない仕様？だったはず

Comment: Gameobject.find系は処理が重いと聞いて、何でもプレハブ化することにこだわってしまい、基礎がおろそかになっていました。インスタンス化されていないのに使えるわけがありませんね。
ProjectViewの仕様は知りませんでした。勉強になりました、ありがとうございます。
※２番目に貼ったコードはコピペミスだったので削除しました。混乱をまねく質問文になったことをお詫びします。

Answer (score 0):

Find系は処理が遅いと言われてますが、繰り返し処理しなければほとんど問題にはなりません。
AwakeやStart、また何らかのトリガから一度のみ行う場合はそんなに神経質にならなくても大丈夫です。
また、それでもFindしたくないのであれば、Publicな変数にCanvasを設定し、インスペクタから設定することでもCanvasを取得することは可能です。
その場合はProjectView内のCanvasではなく、HierarchyView内のCanvasをインスペクタから設定してください。